# How to check and install cron using chef

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

All,

I want to check if cron is installed on a server using chef. If it is not installed it should be installed using chef.

I have written something like this :

```
 yum_package 'cron' do
       action :install
      end
```

It is installing cron. How can I verify before installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to verify anything. Chef is clever enough to know that it shouldn't install a package if it's already there.

From: https://docs.chef.io/resource_examples.html

> Get the package from a remote location, but only if the package does
>   not already exist on the target system

If you want to make sure a particular version is installed, you can specify that. Details here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_yum.html

Comment: the package will be cron or crond